# Can we use TEXT FILE format for Hive Table with Snappy compression?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have an hive external table in the HDFS and i am trying to create a hive managed table above it.i am using textfile format with snappy compression but i want to know how it helps the table.

```
CREATE TABLE standard_cd 
(
    last_update_dttm         TIMESTAMP,
    last_operation_type     CHAR (1) ,
    source_commit_dttm   TIMESTAMP,
    transaction_dttm         TIMESTAMP ,
    transaction_type    CHAR (1)          
) 

PARTITIONED BY (process_dt DATE)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
TBLPROPERTIES  ("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY");
```

Let me know if any issues in creating in this format.

Answer (score 0):

As such their is no issue while creating.
but difference in properties:

Table created and stored as TEXTFILE:

[image]

Table created and stored as ORC:

[image]

although the size of both tables were same after loading some data.

also check documentation about [ORC file format](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC)